# Pandas csv dataframe: Input "Null" into all cells in empty colums, input "NA" into all empty cells in non-empty colums

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working with a large dataset in which I would like to make sure there are no empty cells. However, I'm not too sure how to do the following;

- For all cells in **empty columns**, input "NA"
- For all **empty cells** in **empty columns**, input "null"

Is there a quick way to run through my database and do this? I'm still a beginner so struggling to figure it out myself. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are the empty values "", None, or NaN?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3],
                 "B": [5,3,1],
                 "C": [5,"", 1],
                 "D": ["", "", ""],
                 "E": [3, np.nan, 6],
                 "F": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                 "G": [9, None, 3],
                 "H": [None, None, None]})

for j in df.columns[df.isna().all()|df.eq("").all()].tolist():
    df[j]=np.repeat("NA", 3)

for i, j in zip(*np.where(df.isna()|df.eq(""))):
    df.iloc[i,j]="null"
```

output

```
   A  B  C D    E   F    G     H
0  1  5  5    3.0 NaN  9.0  None
1  2  3       NaN NaN  NaN  None
2  3  1  1    6.0 NaN  3.0  None

   A  B     C   D     E   F     G   H
0  1  5     5  NA   3.0  NA   9.0  NA
1  2  3  null  NA  null  NA  null  NA
2  3  1     1  NA   6.0  NA   3.0  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow! I am also a begginer, but I thought of the following:

Input:

```
     A    B   C  D  E
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1  0
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5  0
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4  0
```

Code:

```
for column in df:
    if df[column].isna().all():
        df[column].fillna(value='NA', inplace=True)
    else:
        df[column].fillna(value='null', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
      A     B   C  D  E
0  null   2.0  NA  0  0
1   3.0   4.0  NA  1  0
2  null  null  NA  5  0
3  null   3.0  NA  4  0
```